# Optimization method L-BFGS-B

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am comparing a result of optimization using R and *Mathematica*.
*Mathematica* (`NMaximize`) has found a significantly better (global optimum) result then R (using [L-BFGS-B](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html)).

The function has 18 variables. The R routine stopped at a place, where none of the gradient is zero. So it's not even a local optimum. I am trying to find out why.

I wonder if I can duplicate the same result in *Mathematica* using the same L-BFGS-B method?

Comment: Quasi-Newton methods use BFGS. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationQuasiNewtonMethods.html

Comment: `NMinimize` uses direct search metaheuristics, not gradient-based methods, and specifically aims to find a global optimum rather than a local one (except perhaps in the case of the Nelder-Mead method). I don't know why R stopped, although maybe the history length was not long enough (there is no reason to use L-BFGS rather than full BFGS for a function of only 18 variables). Anyway, the comparison should be with `FindMinimum`, not `NMinimize`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. The original paper was written in 2003. The goal was still to find a global optima. I will try `FindMinimum` on the same problem and see what happens. I think it may be it was just an old version of R? which caused it to stop at a bad place (or even a local).

Comment: Differential evolution (the most powerful method offered by `NMinimize`) was invented in 1995, while direct search methods started to be considered respectable for global optimization some time in the early 80s. (The Nelder-Mead method was invented in 1965.) So, really, a paper written in 2003 should not have used BFGS to try to find a global optimum, unless it was also known that the function is uniformly convex. But, if so, (L-)BFGS should not stop. So, it sounds like either a bug or a bad choice of method.